# Projecting an old Ordnance Survey map in Cassini-Soldner Grid

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, ordnance-survey

I have an Ordnance Survey map of North West England (1921, quarter inch to the mile) that doesn't conform to British National Grid/EPSG:27700. I suspect that the projection might be Cassini-Soldner Grid. What's the process for building a custom CRS to view this map in its original projection in QGIS?

Apologies, my knowledge of QGIS is fairly basic and I can't make much of the answers to related questions I found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183667/crs-and-qgis-georeferencing-for-cassini-projection) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144668/using-cassini-soldner-projection-in-qgis).

The corners of the map have the following approximate lat/longs: Bottom LHS = 53deg 36.5'N, 4deg 58.5'W; Bottom RHS = 53deg 37'N, 2deg 20'W; Top LHS = 54deg 38'N, 5deg 1'W; Top RHS = 54deg 39.5'N 2deg 20.5'W

Link to the map [here](https://maps.nls.uk/view/239443201).

Edit: I used the following string to make a custom CRS

```
+proj=cass \
  +lat_0=53.221465 +lon_0=-2.684323 \
  +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=airy
```

And then georeferenced the map reading the lat/longs from the corners, setting the layer and project to my custom CRS, and got the following skewed map. [image: skewed map]
So either the map wasn't originally projected in Cassini-Soldner or perhaps there's something wrong with the string I've used?

Comment: Why not simply georeference the map?

Comment: I'd like to keep the shape and proportions of the original OS map. Georeferencing to another CRS, EPSG:27700 for example, results in a map that's no longer square.

Comment: Can you tell us any more? Like the title, edition, any cartographic details in the legend etc? Are there any grid lines or margin grid segments, and how do they relate to lat-long lines?

Comment: I've added a link to the map.

Comment: There is an older question on this projection - there might be some adjustment required https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/144672/276

Comment: Yes, I've seen that (I linked to it in my question). There's a lot that I don't know how to apply to my map. For example -  "You need the center coordinates of the 31 local Cassini Soldner projections, which you can find here: http://www.globogis.it/le-origini-delle-coordinate-cassini-soldner"

Comment: I can't answer your whole question but you can find those coords via the internet archive:  https://web.archive.org/web/20210506151119/https://www.globogis.it/le-origini-delle-coordinate-cassini-soldner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NLS web site tells us that the maps are constructed on Cassini's projection with a point of origin at Delamere Forest:

https://maps.nls.uk/os/quarter-inch-third/

Which Wikipedia sites at: 53.2291, -2.6778

Hence you should be able to construct a Proj string for this projection, now you know the long and lat origin points.

The parameters for a Cassini projection in Proj are given here:

https://proj.org/en/9.3/operations/projections/cass.html

The only ones you really need are the ellipsoid specifications. Its 1921, so probably the Airy 1830 ellipsoid that was used in 1936. `proj` has a name for that:

```
$ proj -le| grep -i airy
     airy a=6377563.396    rf=299.3249646   Airy 1830
```

The rest of the parameters control the grid coordinates, so are essentially up to you since there's no grid numbers on the map you want to match with. As defined you'll get a (0,0) grid location at Delamere Forest, and you can choose any units (metres, feet, miles, us-ft if you're a masochist) with appropriate parameters. There's also the offset parameters that will shift the origin point, so that for example Delamere Forest becomes (1000,1000) and all other coordinates change similarly.

So I'd start with something like:

```
+proj=cass \
  +lat_0=53.2291 +lon_0=-2.6778 \
  +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=airy
```

and that will probably get you metres from Delamere Forest.

Annoyingly I can't see any reason Delamere Forest is being used, or a special point in the forest that would be a more precise reference (the coords above are just Wikipedia's coordinates)...

Update: "Delamere meridian (latitude 53º13’17”274N, longitude 2º41’03”562W) was adopted as the single..." from

https://delamereandoakmere.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Delamere-Meridian.pdf

and

https://www.sandstoneridge.org.uk/news/delamere-meridian-1.html

So you'll get a better result if you convert those coords to decimal and use in the proj string. Good luck!